# The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.8.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0' or higher to enable null safety

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies

[image]

i'm facing this issue i'm new in flutter please help me to solve this issue
thanks

i tried to change sdk to
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

but still i face issue i don't know why i also change sdk to
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.6'

but i again face same error

**HERE IS COMPLETE ERROR**
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.8.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.

The current Dart SDK (3.0.6) only supports null safety.

For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: You can manage versions through FVM(flutter version management)

Comment: Can you run and show _flutter doctor_ output?

Comment: If your previous code was only 2.8 minsdk, it needs to go through a null migration.  There are plenty of articles about that.  And that must happen before you install flutter 3.10 (dart 3.0) because Dart 3 doesn't support pre-NNBD code.  If you need multiple flutter installations at the same time, see my video at https://youtu.be/olqmK-opexA

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

- Migrate sdk to latest version or version >=2.12.0 in your **pubspec.yaml**, eg: *sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'*
- run **dart analyze .** and correct the errors it outputs.

For more information about Dart 3 migration, check [here](https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration).

Answer (score 0):

run `flutter upgrade` command in the console to upgrade flutter and dart

Answer (score 0):

Since Dart 3 requires strict null-safety (sound null-safety) support for the code and all dependencies, you can try downgrade to flutter 3.7.12 (based on dart 2.19.6):

```
flutter downgrade 3.7.12
```

Or follow the link and download manually:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive