# Strange error when running flutter pub add flutter_icons

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope I'm missing something trivial here. When I run
`flutter pub add flutter_icons`
I get the error:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.6.

Because <app_name> depends on flutter_icons any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
```

I'm reading this to mean I need dart version higher than 2.12.0 and I have dart version 3.0.6.

```
dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.0.6 (stable) (Tue Jul 11 18:49:07 2023 +0000) on "macos_arm64"
```

pubspec.yaml is simple:

```
name: <app_name>
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 0.0.1+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  english_words: ^4.0.0
  provider: ^6.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
uses-material-design: true
```

I'm expecting it to build without error because I have a null safe version of dart.
I'm new to flutter, so probably missing something obvious.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just found this question that looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76752983/the-lower-bound-of-sdk-2-8-0-3-0-0-must-be-2-12-0-or-higher-to-enable-n?rq=2
I'm working through the suggestions now.  dart analyse shows no errors.

Comment: it is because the `flutter_icons` plugin requires `>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0` Dart version, but your Dart version is higher than that bounds, you can reinstall a lower version Dart SDK, or try `flutter_icons_null_safety` plugin

Comment: @Zhentao - thanks that's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

hi [flutter_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons) package is incomputable for dart 3 and it doesn't have null safety,
where as your Flutter need null safety. either you can downgrade your flutter or try to find some other package. i recommend to search for other package.

why u need this package?

**Edit 2:**

try this package [flutter_font_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_font_icons) it is updated

```
flutter pub add flutter_font_icons
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm trying to install that package because I'm running through this tutorial (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first) and for some reason, none of the icons (e.g. favourite) are showing.  I'm hacking to see if I can resolve it.  I tried the package you suggested, that works, but icons are still not showing.

Comment: @markhardwick for that type of icons you don't need this external package u can use `Icon(Icons.favorite_border)` as default u can also use CupertinoIcons by `Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart)` which is in cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 package